# Adding distinct to my sql query makes it load for a long time and not work

Tags: sql, distinct

This code works well in sql but when I add distinct after the select statement it just loads and hangs. How do I go about this to avoid the very slow loading? I need the distinct analysis name since I will be making another column that will count the analysis done by different analysts.

```
SELECT ANALYSIS.NAME
FROM ANALYSIS
    ,BATCH
    ,PROJECT
    ,TEST
    ,SAMPLE
    ,VERSIONS
WHERE (BATCH.C_ANALYZED_BY = 'analyst')
    AND (
        BATCH.C_DATE_ANALYZED BETWEEN {ts '2020-01-01 06:37:24' }
            AND {ts '2020-11-20 06:37:35' }
        )
    AND (PROJECT.GROUP_NAME = 'site')
    AND (TEST.ANALYSIS = ANALYSIS.NAME)
    AND (ANALYSIS.VERSION = VERSIONS.VERSION)
    AND (VERSIONS.TABLE_NAME = 'ANALYSIS')
    AND (VERSIONS.NAME = ANALYSIS.NAME)
    AND (TEST.BATCH = BATCH.NAME)
    AND (SAMPLE.PROJECT = PROJECT.NAME)
    AND (TEST.SAMPLE_NUMBER = SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NUMBER)
ORDER BY BATCH.C_DATE_ANALYZED ASC
```

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY` instead? It can sometimes be quicker than `DISTINCT`, although not guaranteed. You might also look into optimising the table(s) themselves.

Comment: The 'order by' doesn't seem to add a lot of value if you want distinct analyst names. I also don't see the point in including the TEST,SAMPLE or VERSIONS tables. Using the standard JOIN format can often be faster than WHERE, depending on the DB

Comment: ...and finally, if you want to total by analYST, why are you grouping on the analySIS name? I think you should complete your query and optimise it as a whole.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and performance tuning is quite product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)